# Flask wtforms not allowing image upload

Tags: python, html, flask, flask-wtforms

Dears,
I have been struggling with uploading an image on a flask form in my application. I have simplified the code to just show if the form has picked up a file by a print statement. The script is as follows:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, session, redirect, url_for
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import  SubmitField
from flask_wtf.file import FileField
from PIL import Image
import os
from main import app

class Uploadform(FlaskForm):

    picture = FileField('Update Profile Pic')
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')


#### route
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload():

    form = Uploadform()
    path = app.root_path

    if form.validate_on_submit:
        print('form submitted')
        if form.picture.data:
            print('image available')
            img = form.picture.data
            print(img)

        else:
            print('no image')
            

    return render_template ('form.html', form=form)

if  __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

HTML form goes a follows:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST" action="{{url_for('upload')}}">

    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    {{ form.csrf_token }}
    {{form.picture.label}} <br>
    {{form.picture}} <br>
    {{form.submit() }} <br>


    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run the above I get the print statements:
'form submitted' and
'no image'

Many thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
<form method="POST" action="{{url_for('upload')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

`multipart/form-data` this value is necessary if the user will upload a file through the form.

Answer (score 0):

```
if form.validate_on_submit:
```

needs to be

```
if form.validate_on_submit():
```